# animation: make water wave

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I would like to build a simple animation for a school project.

I want to make water wave within a box in such a way that tilting the device causes the water to wave in a direction rather the other.

Is there a sample from where I can start to create such effect? Any help is super appreciated.

Thx,
mE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once did a water project for an animation class... one site that I relied on as a reference was [here](http://www.vterrain.org/Water/), and in particular, [this article](http://www.gamasutra.com/gdce/2001/jensen/jensen_01.htm) on wave rendering, which is generally good in its discussion of refraction.

Comment: Thanks this gives me some background in finding the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use Lottie animation. That's so simple way to implement with some lines of code.

Comment: Can you please include a link to it and some details on what it is?